# Which movie ended with the male protagonist's mother in the body of his girlfriend?

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror, science-fiction, thriller

When I was I kid I watched this film on CINEMAX about 8 years ago. I tried searching it using the description of the ending and I cannot find it.

**Info about the movie:** 
Probably released around the 1980s, colored.
The plot revolves around this device called **BLENDER**, a device/machine which blends two persons -- that is the mind from one and the body from the other.

My apologies but I do not remember much from the premise but I remember how it ends.

**Ending:**

After an explosion, the male protagonist's sociopath(?) mother is in the body of his girlfriend. The mother (in the girlfriend's body) pushes the face of his son towards her breasts and says "kiss your mother" as the protagonist cries and screams in despair.

**Main actor:** 
A white teenager who has a very awkward demeanor like *Michael Angarano*

**Other info:**

- There is a scene where the protagonist's mother pushes a man in a wheelchair to the Blender machine muttering in non-verbatim "Mixing my two persons I love the most"

Does anyone know the title of this film? If so, please tell me.

Comment: Welcome to [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/tour). Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Comment: Thank you for the additional details and elaborations. Your question has been reopened.

Comment: Is there a reward for Most Improved ID Question? ;)

Comment: @Walt Other than getting reopened and answered? Becoming a Hot Network Question, apparently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for [Severed Ties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Severed_Ties_(film)) from 1992.

> Severed Ties is a 1992 comedy horror film directed by Damon Santostefano. It was released to video by Columbia TriStar Home Video. A regeneration experiment on a severed arm goes awry, turning the limb into a murderous, reptilian creature.

It ends exactly as you described (the mother's brain in the girlfriend's body, what she says to him and his horrified reaction, and then the guy in a wheelchair reluctantly pushed into the machine to blend "the two most important men in her life"). Here's the trailer (the first one in this 2-parter):